# Python close_fds not clear

Tags: python, process, parent-child, file-descriptor

I had an issue with `close_fds` in Python27 so after doing some research I found this [example](http://bugs.python.org/issue7213):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
p1 = Popen(['cat'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(['grep', 'a'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdin.write("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n")
p1.stdin.close()
p2.stdout.read()
```

My problem is that I can't understand why `p1.stdin` remains open. `p1` is not a child of `p2` so `p2` shouldn't inherit any `p1` resource except `p1.stdout` which is explicitly passed. Furthermore why setting `close_fds=True` in `p2` resolves the issue? [Here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) is written this:

> If close_fds is true, all file descriptors except 0, 1 and 2 will be closed before the child process is executed.

So even if I will be able to understand the inheritance between `p1` and `p2` still `p1.stdin` shouldn't be closed by `close_fds=True` because it is the standard input (1).

Comment: Interestingly, `p1.stdin` does not remain open in 2.7.7 on linux.  When I checked the open fds for p2 before calling `p1.stdin.close`, p2 did not have any extra fds. Not sure why that is happening now. This is on linux. Has something changed recently in the implementation?

Comment: It seems like fds to actual files and terminals are inherited, but not fds to pipes?

Comment: Btw, it looks like this behavior in 2.7.7 is due to commit https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/2a34eb31040ad3eb2f09e22a0237afa98755390d#diff-cc136486b4a8e112e64b57436a0619eb, which ensures that CLOEXEC is set on any pipe, thereby making them uninheritable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since `p1` and `p2` are siblings, there is no inheritance going on between their corresponding processes directly.

However, consider the file descriptor that the parent sees as `p1.stdin`, inherited by `p1` and redirected to its `stdin`. This file descriptor exists in the parent process (with a number other than 0, 1, or 2 - you can verify this by printing `p1.stdin.fileno()`), and it has to exist, because we intend to write to it from the parent. It is this file descriptor that is unintentionally inherited and kept open by `p2`.

When an open file is referenced by multiple file descriptors, as is the case with `p1.stdin`, it is only closed when **all** the descriptors are closed. This is why it is necessary to both close `p1.stdin` *and* pass `close_fds` to `p2`. (If you implemented the spawning code manually, you would simply close the file descriptor after the second `fork()`.)

Comment: Ok now it is clearer. So there is a fd for the PIPE used to communicate with p1 which is inherited and not closed AND a fd p1.stdin which is different (I have not clear it in terms of pointers and addresses) and correctly opened/closed. Now the hangs in read() is due to the open PIPE inherited which waits to be closed. Is that correct? Could I close the PIPE from p2? Could you explain me the difference between the PIPE used to communicate to p1 and p1.stdin, aren't they the same? Thank you very much

Comment: @LuigiTiburzi `p1.stdin` is the Python object wrapper around the fd - they are one and the same. You could close the descriptor from p2, except that you are not given control over p2 by Python. This is why close_fds resolves the issue.

Comment: If they are one and the same, p1.stdin closes this resource, then why the same resource is seen open by p2? Speaking in terms of pointers, there is a certain address to the stdin of p1. p1.stdin points at that address and closes it (p1.stdin.close()). p2 inherit that address from the common Parent, so points to the p1 stdin too. Now why it sees the resource open? Thank you and sorry for the many questions

Comment: @LuigiTiburzi `p1.stdin` and its file descriptor are one and the same underlying resource (the file descriptor - pointers are irrelevant, since open file is an OS-level resource allocated by the kernel). The `p2` process inherits the file descriptor, and that copy remains open. This is why closing `p1.stdin` (nor its file descriptor) doesn't help. You can think of file descriptors as being references ton an "open file" - closing the descriptor removes a single reference to the open file. Only when all file descriptors are closed does the open file really get closed.

Comment: Ok so it is more like a passing by value rather then a passing by reference when talking about fd. Now it's clear. Thank you very much!

Comment: @LuigiTiburzi It's kind of pass-by-reference because all fd's point to the same open file resource. But the underlying resource is reference-counted, so it gets closed only when *all* of its references get closed.

Comment: @user4815162342 Then why setting `close_fds=True` to `p2` solves the blocking issue? It seems that setting `close_fds=True` has nothing to do with the `stdin` of both parent process and `p2`.

Comment: @LancelodLiu Creating `p2` with `close_fds=True` solves the issue because it makes sure that `p2` doesn't inherit the `p1.stdin` endpoint of the pipe used to communicate with `p1`. The key point is that `p1.stdin` is **not** stdin (or stdout) in the parent - it is the file object corresponding to the pipe used to communicate with `p1`. As the answer says, you can verify that it has a number other than (0, 1, 2) by printing `p1.stdin.fileno()`. Passing `close_fds=True` when spawning `p2` parent makes sure that `p1.stdin` is closed *in the p2 process*. (It is closed explicitly in the parent.)